# Understanding Put/Get in mpi4py

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I'm learning how to use one-sided communication in mpi4py. To test my understanding, I came up with this contrived example:

```
import mpi4py.MPI as mpi
import numpy as np
import time

def main():
    rank = mpi.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
    n_proc = mpi.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()

    assert(n_proc == 2)

    buff = np.zeros(10, dtype='d')
    win = mpi.Win.Create(buff, 1, mpi.INFO_NULL, mpi.COMM_WORLD)

    if (rank == 0):
        win.Lock(1)
        win.Put([buff, mpi.DOUBLE], 1)
        win.Unlock(1)

        buff[-1] = 9
        time.sleep(30)

        win.Lock(1)
        win.Put([buff, mpi.DOUBLE], 1)
        win.Unlock(1)

    else:
        holder = np.zeros(10)
        failures = 0
        while (holder[-1] != 9):
            failures += 1
            win.Lock(0)
            win.Get([holder, mpi.DOUBLE], 0)
            win.Unlock(0)
        print('Took', failures, 'dials')

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I expect this to work as follows: rank 0 will wait for 30 seconds before placing the ndarray containing `[0, 0, ..., 0, 9]` into the shared memory. Meanwhile, rank 1 will continuously check to see if rank 0 has updated its shared memory---once it has, it will print out what it sees. Specifically, *I would expect that rank 1 would execute its while loop many many times* during the 30 second wait while rank 0 is idle. However, when I run this code with `mpirun -n 2 python mwe.py`, I consistently get this output:

```
Took 2 dials
```

indicating that the call to `Get` only happened twice.

**Specific question:** Why are there only two calls to `Get` from rank 1?

**More vague question:** Am I making an obvious mistakes in this MWE? I am pretty new to mpi4py/MPI in general.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating as you said correctly a *shared* memory window. The window grants other MPI processes in the communicator direct access to the exact memory where your `buff` is stored. When you change `buff[-1] = 9` this is ofcourse stored in said memory and the window is immediatly affected. Thus, the explicit `Put` call to the local process (from rank 0 to rank 0) is unnecessary and `Put` is useful only to place data in **remote** memory windows. The other MPI processes can start reading out your changed `buff` variable from the window before rank 0 even begins its 30 second sleep operation.

Unfortunately the reason why you see "Took 2 dials" is because rank 0 and 1 execute their first lock and unlock probably at the same time, then rank 0 executes the `buff[-1] = 9` and then the loop repeats on rank 1 and it reads the updated buffer and exits after 2 iterations.

PS: To test, place a 1s sleep before `buff[-1] = 9`

Comment: "rank 0 and 1 execute their first lock and unlock probably at the same time" Python makes the locks by default exclusive.